# std::atomics and std::lock_guard or only std::lock_guard

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stl

I have a function `foo` run in many threads (`std::thread t([&]() { foo(a); }`):

```
void foo(int a)
{
    if (x && y != a)
    {
        ++x;
        y = a;
        vec.push_back(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now());
    }
}
```

I need to protect `int x`, `int y` and `std::vector<> vec` against race condition.
What is the best solution.

To define `x` and `y` as `std::atomic` and use `std::lock_guard(mutex)` before pushing to `vec`.

Or `std::lock_guard` for the whole body of `if` statement?

Or maybe any better solution?

Comment: Personally I would lock the whole thing since the whole operation seems like it should not be interleaved.

Comment: After you test if `y != 5` do you mind if another thread changes `y` before you get to the line `y = 5`?

Answer (score 1):

Without more of the context it's hard to be sure, but it looks like you're using and modifying `y`, so you'll likely need to lock it from before the `if` until after the assignment.  That can't be done with a `std::atomic`.  Given that you're then mutexing that region of code, you're getting little benefit (here) from making `x` atomic.  But you haven't shown us anything reading from it, so it's hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat dependant on what the threads are doing the rest of the time, where x and y are used, but as a general rule of thumb, the less locks you do the better.